# How to split the prefix of currency symbol in separate column in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
    Amount
0   250000
1   ₹40,000,000
2   ₹65,000,000
3   2000000
4   —
... ...
521 225000000
522 —
523 7500
524 ₹35,000,000
525 35000000
526 rows × 1 columns
```

how can we split the Amount column in separate of Currency Symbol and amount in separate column

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df[['currency', 'Amount']] = df['Amount'].str.extract(r'(\D*)(\d.*)')
```

Output:

```
         Amount currency
0        250000         
1    40,000,000        ₹
2    65,000,000        ₹
3       2000000         
4           NaN      NaN
521   225000000         
522         NaN      NaN
523        7500         
524  35,000,000        ₹
525    35000000
```

If you further need to convert to number:

```
df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'].str.replace(',', ''))
```

Output:

```
          Amount currency
0       250000.0         
1     40000000.0        ₹
2     65000000.0        ₹
3      2000000.0         
4            NaN      NaN
521  225000000.0         
522          NaN      NaN
523       7500.0         
524   35000000.0        ₹
525   35000000.0
```